# Building an imaging array with multiple sensors?

Tags: lens, sensor

If I purchased [two image sensors that had a resolution of 80x62](https://www.waveshare.com/thermal-camera.htm) with 45 degree field of view, would there be an easy way to concentrate two sensors into a resolution of 2x(80x62) with a 45 degree field of view? Is there a mechanism that can easily reduce the field of view to 1/2 so I can run two sensors in an array and get the full field of view at 2x resolution.

Things like the [195 gigapixel photo](https://www.dezeen.com/2019/01/15/195-gigapixel-high-resolution-photo-shaghai-bigpixel/) are made this way,

> The reality, according to Bigpixel, is that the image is stitched together from thousands of smaller photos taken by regular cameras with 600 millimetre telephoto lenses to capture close-ups.

So they're using thousands of cameras with telephoto lenses. I want to do the same thing with two lenses with a 45 degree angle, perhaps focusing the 45 degree angle field of view, to a 22.5 deg field of a view, and then "stitch" it together with another camera and lens of the same sort.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt using two separate sensors would work but several cameras, e.g. Panasonic G9, have a high resolution mode in which the sensor is shifted by small amounts in different directions to build up an image with 2x the resolution. Normal image size is ~20 megapixels. A high resolution image is ~80 megapixels. Of course one limitation is that the subject can't move as the sensor is being shifted.

Answer (score 1):

The image sensor alone does not have a specific field of view. You would want to pair the sensors with lenses so that the recorded field of view was 22.5˚ each; and then stitch those images together to get the 45˚ field of view of the final image.

You can use something like a speed booster to concentrate the lens' wider field of view to fit a smaller sensor... e.g. 45˚ to 22.5˚; but that only works if the sensor/lens combination is a "crop sensor" (e.g. m/4/3 with a FF lens).

---

Edit:

Those cameras do have lenses incorporated. You cannot change/compress their fields of view without distorting the scene being recorded.

You could stitch the two 45˚ fields of view and crop out whatever you wanted, but that makes no sense if you are wanting 45˚ FOV to start with. Your best bet is to stack the two images for a "pixel shift" type of image resolution improvement.

Comment: The sensors that i'm looking at do have  a field of view, i'm guessing they're attached to a lens? I'm looking at thermal sensors like the MLX90640 and wondering essentially how i can make multiple cheap thermal sensors into a higher resolution and usable thermal camera. I can do  the stitching in software. I'm just wondering how you'd go about  going from sensors to camera in hardware. https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832775772263.html

Comment: or this sensor which is attached to a pi hat, https://www.waveshare.com/thermal-camera.htm

Comment: Added to my answer based on your comments...